# How to read output from an application using python

Tags: python, tcp

Currently trying to record a list of outgoing TCP connections and then compare the present list to the previous list in order to see what connections have been established. However, TCPView.exe seems to be of no luck. I am able to run the application with this:

```
def get_tcp_conns():
    process = Popen([r"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\TCPView\Tcpview.exe"], stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    for line in io.TextIOWrapper(proc.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):
        print(line)  # Do whatever here
```

However, this is not returning any text. Not for sure where to go with this as I have no idea how to read the TCP information in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be something like

```
import subprocess 

def get_tcp_conns():
    process = subprocess.run("C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe './C:Users/PC/Downloads/TCPView/Tcpview.exe' ", shell=True, capture_output=True)
    print(process.stdout)
```