# How to read text output from an application using python 3.9

Tags: python, tcp

Currently trying to record a list of outgoing TCP connections and then compare the present list to the previous list in order to see what connections have been established. However, TCPView.exe seems to be of no luck. I am able to run the application with this:

```
def get_tcp_conns():
    process = Popen([r"C:\Users\PC\Downloads\TCPView\Tcpview.exe"], stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    for line in io.TextIOWrapper(proc.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):
        print(line)  # Do whatever here
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read output from an application using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64638025/how-to-read-output-from-an-application-using-python)

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. This is the same as the last one, only with less text.